# c++ error: expected primary-expression before '&' token

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and I have the following code which gives an error in line 39 (fill_file() call).  I've searched on the web for a solution but can't find why I get this error (expected primary-expression before '&' token).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

void fill_file(vector<Point>& original_points) {
    string outputfile="mydata.txt";
    ofstream ost{outputfile};
    if(!ost) error("Can't open outputfile ", outputfile);
    for(int i=0;i<original_points.size();i++) {
        ost << original_points[i].x << " " << original_points[i].y << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter 3 points with a value: " << endl;
    vector<Point> original_points;
    Point p;
    double x;
    double y;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        cin>>p.x;
        cin>>p.y;
        original_points.push_back(p);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl << "Points: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<original_points.size();i++) {
        cout << original_points[i].x << " " << original_points[i].y << endl;
        /* ost << original_points[i].x << " " << original_points[i].y << endl; */
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    fill_file(vector<Point>& original_points);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thx for the help!!

Comment: just `fill_file(original_points);`

Answer (score 5):

You made a mistake when you called your fill_file function:

```
fill_file(vector<Point>& original_points);
```

must be called like this:

```
fill_file(original_points);
```

Answer (score 4):

You made an error calling the function `fill_file()`. Currently you call it like this:

```
fill_file(vector<Point>& original_points);
```

This above, I presume is a copy paste error. What I thing you want to do is:

```
fill_file(original_points);
```

because `original_points` is the actual variable, not `vector<Point>& original_points`. As your error states:

> expected primary-expression before '&' token

As seen above, you are putting a random l-value in the function call, and this is not allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still a newbie.  I understand it now: don't use the type of an argument in the call (only in the declaration and definition) of a function.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct, if you feel it is so.

Comment: The answers above are correct.  How do I flag/mark the answer correct?

Comment: Click the green checkmark icon below the down arrow.

Comment: I don't see a green checkmark icon below the down arrow, only a gray star to mark the question as a favorite question.

Comment: This may be because the question is old, so I don't think that you can mark it correct now. Unless you are looking in the wrong place. Check the arrow below _my_ answer.